# how to add logo in asp.net mvc Tridion content delivery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Am confused to add a Logo in `asp.net`. I have tried adding but Logo is not showing up properly.

```
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("student marksheet", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="jee">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("class", "class", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("mark1", "mark1", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("mark2", "mark2", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? What the errors you are getting? You should provide us more details.

Comment: Hello @Jeevitha, please update the post including the code what you have done so far, so that we can help you out exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This makes your post more valid and easy to read. Please also add some more examples in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="~/Images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>
  ...
</nav>
```

Make sure that the *wwwroot*  folder has an **Images** folder and the **logo.jpg** is present inside this folder.